# Как отследить нажатие enter в <TextInput/> react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

При вводе данных в  получаю undefined

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
class SearchCityScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  handleKeyPress = (e) => {
    console.log(e.key);
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      console.log("do validate");
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput style={styles.textInput} onKeyPress={this.handleKeyPress} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: `e.code === 'Enter'` . Можно ещё попробовать засунуть инпут в форму и следить за `submit`, он отработает по `Enter`'y

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можете попробовать колбэк onBlur